# Looking for an analogue to pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates() where order does not matter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, drop-duplicates

I would like to use something similar to dropping the duplicates of a DataFrame. I would like columns' order not to matter. What I mean is that the function shuold consider a row consisting of the entries `'a', 'b'` to be identical to a row consisting of the entries `'b', 'a'`. For example, given

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']])

   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
2  a  b
3  b  a
```

I would like to obtain:

```
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

where the preference is for efficiency, as I run this on a huge dataset within a groupby operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `np.sort` first, and then drop duplicates.

```
df[:] = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates()

   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you use the `:` in the first row? Why not just `df = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)`?

Comment: @splinter It's a little technique I use for updating the dataframe inplace without creating a new one. `np.sort` returns an array. I assign it back to `df` using `df[:] = ...`